# Add next control in a panel from top

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have added pdf image hyperlinks dynamically in a panel from code behind, which is in ItemTemplate in RadListView. After every 3rd hyperlink, the next hyperlink should start in the next column from top.
I have added the hyperlink but after 3rd hyperlink the next hyperlink does not start from top .
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<style>
    .column {
        width: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5%;
        padding: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
             }

    .column:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: right;
    }
</style>
```

Code Behind-

```
protected void RadListView1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RadListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is RadListViewDataItem)
    {
        var dataItem = ((RadListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem;
        // Get the data item for the current item
        //DataRowView dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

        // Find the Panel control in the ItemTemplate
        Panel panel1 = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        
        if (panel1 != null)
        {
            // Set the properties of the Panel control based on the data item
            
            ProjectDetailsBLL projectDetailsBll = new ProjectDetailsBLL();
            List<string> emailAttachments= projectDetailsBll.GetCrmEmailLogsAttachment(Request.QueryString["proposalBuiltID"], Request.QueryString["changeOrderId"]);

            List<HyperLink> links = new List<HyperLink>(); ;
            foreach (var attachment in emailAttachments)
            {
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment),Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment),ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });
                links.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl(attachment), Target = "_blank", ImageUrl = SelectImage(attachment), ToolTip = Path.GetFileName(attachment) });

            }

            int count = 0;
            Panel panel2 = null;
            // Add the HyperLink controls to the Panel control
            foreach (HyperLink link in links)
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(link);
                panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));

                // Create a new column after every 3 links
                if (count % 3 == 0)
                {
                    panel2 = new Panel();
                    panel2.CssClass = "column";
                    panel1.Controls.Add(panel2);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));
                }

                //Panel panel2 = panel1.Controls[panel1.Controls.Count - 1] as Panel;
                if (panel2 != null)
                {
                    panel2.Controls.Add(link);
                    panel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));
                }

                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Generated HTML Code-

```
        <tr height="20">
                <td class="Heading">
                    Attachment: 
                   
                </td>
           
                <td class="row">

                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <div >
                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_RadListView1_ctrl0_Panel1">
<br /><br /><div class="column">
    <a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br /><a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br /><a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br />
</div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><div class="column">
    <a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br /><a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br /><a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br />
</div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><div class="column">
    <a title="Proposal.pdf" href="\\hggd.com\EmailAttachments\638133556853615096_61507_0_0\Proposal.pdf" target="_blank"><img title="Proposal.pdf" src="images/acrobat.gif" alt="" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><br /><br />
</div><br/><br/></div></div></td><td class="row"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Hi. What is the HTML code that is generated?

Comment: I have added generated html code

Comment: Why not use itemteamplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `display: flex;` property to the parent `div` (the one with id `ctl00_MainContent_RadListView1_ctrl0_Panel1`) it should be fixed. Try:

```
#ctl00_MainContent_RadListView1_ctrl0_Panel1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

However, I think that the problem is all those `<br>` you added. Try removing them.